# Random number generator issues in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I have an issue I can't quite figure out. For a simulation I generate artificial data randomly, with randomly drawn variance and a mean of 0. To acheive this I first create a vector of possible variances and then randomly draw the index for the vector, like in the following example

```
%% Covariance Matrix

% Variances of explanatory variables
var1 = 0.1:0.1:100;
var2 = 0.1:0.1:100;
var3 = 0.1:0.1:100;

%% Randomly selecting variances

% if exist('s','var')
%     rng(s) % Loading Random generator settings for replication
% else
%     s=rng; % Saving Random generator settings for replication
% end

ind_1=randi([0 1000]);
ind_2=randi([0 1000]);
ind_3=randi([0 1000]);

var_11=var1(ind_1);
var_22=var2(ind_2);
var_33=var3(ind_3);
```

For some reason the random number generator seems to give me the same numbers  in the first (ind_1=815, ind_2=906, ind_3=127) and in the second run (ind_1=914, ind_2=632, ind_3=97) after restarting matlab, if I generate the vector of variances first. I've been able to replicate that on different PC as well. Is there a feature that I'm overlooking or am I making, and I would imagine I am, a crucial mistake? (I am well aware that there are only pseudo random numbers in matlab, but this seems too pseudo for my taste.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the seed generator in matlab, when you start matlab is always the same take a look at this

```
>> rng('default')
>> ind_1=randi([0 1000])
ind_2=randi([0 1000])
ind_3=randi([0 1000])
ind_1=randi([0 1000])
ind_2=randi([0 1000])
ind_3=randi([0 1000])
rng('default')
ind_1=randi([0 1000])
ind_2=randi([0 1000])
ind_3=randi([0 1000])

ind_1 =

   815


ind_2 =

   906


ind_3 =

   127


ind_1 =

   914


ind_2 =

   632


ind_3 =

    97


ind_1 =

   815


ind_2 =

   906


ind_3 =

   127
```

So the only thing that you have to do is change the initial seed every time you generate new numbers.

Execute before [`rng('shuffle')`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/generate-random-numbers-that-are-different.html), it reseeds the generator using a different seed based on the current time.

```
>> rng('default')
>> [randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000])]

ans =

   815   906   127

>> rng('shuffle')
>> [randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000])]

ans =

   404    10   838

>> [randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000])]

ans =

    31   459   534

>> rng('shuffle')
>> rng('shuffle')
>> [randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000])]

ans =

   708   963    21

>> rng('default')
>> [randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000])]

ans =

   815   906   127

>> [randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000])]

ans =

   914   632    97

>> rng('default')
>> [randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000]), randi([0 1000])]

ans =

   815   906   127
```