# Simulink simulation and random numbers - Reset normrnd

Tags: matlab, random, simulink, random-seed

I would like to use `normrnd()` on MATLAB Simulink, but every simulation instance provides the same random timeseries of random variables. How can I reset it every time I run the simulink simulation?

Comment: With “reset” you mean you want to start at a different place in the sequence for each instance?

Comment: I think `rng('shuffle')` is what you’re after:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45348145/7328782

Comment: In the [documentation for normrnd](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html) we see this: "*rng('default') % For reproducibility*". This seems highly suspect. Does the problem persist if you pass *something else* (whatever you can legally pass) instead of just 'default' ? Typically, when you do NOT want reproducibility, you *seed* your pseudo-random number generator with some hash of the launch time.

Comment: My concern regards the Simuink scope. How to setup rng for a Simulink instance?